# One Month Rails - Install Bootstrap-sass gem

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Please help! I'm an extreme noob. https://github.com/MikeNaha1. I've gotten to Install Bootstraps Gem on Mattan's One Month Rails tutorial. I followed all the instructions, bundled successfully, but my localhost:3000 displays an error. I have a feeling like the gem was updated and One Month hasn't amended their video yet.

File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.

```
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>Pinteresting</title>
            <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
            <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
          <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
             </head>
```

Comment: show me what error are you getting it?

Comment: Can you share your gem file? Also, are you using the same version of Ruby & Rails as the OM Rails tutorial? There are also a multiple Bootstrap related gems. Did you select the proper gem according to the tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

it sound like you did not install bootstrap properly but no worry there is gem for that. it's page on Github is a good place to start.

https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails#installing-gem

Put it in your `Gemfile`.

`$ bundle install`

Then continue reading the instructions there. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found CDN links are good alternatives to gem. Just include the two links below to your layout file.

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Just they shouldn't be used together with the gem, as you don't want to load the same thing twice.