# Installing Bootstrap-sass gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a similar problem as this guy: 
[One Month Rails - Install Bootstrap-sass gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366847/one-month-rails-install-bootstrap-sass-gem)

Mine doesn't give me any error, but stays the same.
Bootstrap won't be applied, and the webpage looks the same.

What I did was: add gem `'bootstrap-sass'`, then run `bundle install`

After that, I made a new file on stylesheets and entered

```
@import 'bootstrap';
```

What did I do wrong?:(((

Comment: Can you give us what you put in your css, js? How you import the required files? Did you follow the [instructions](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#usage)

Comment: Did you re-start your server?  Have you cleared browser caches?  Try putting that `import` statement in your `application.css.scss` file, not a new file.

Answer (score 0):

Rename your *application.css** to **application.scss**

i.e. `mv app/assets/stylesheets/application.css app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`

Then, remove all the **//= require** and **//= require_tree** statements from the file.